# What is the Lebesgue measure on the circle?

Tags: measure-theory

What is the Lebesgue measure on the unit circle ? Would it be : for $m(\{e^{it}\mid t\in [0,\theta ]\})=\theta $ ? I'm quite confuse with this. I also tried as $\mathbb S^1=\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2=1\}$, and thus, try to use $$m(B)=\int_B \sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}dx,$$
for $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$, but this work only for the half circle... Is there any convention ?

Comment: Actually it is a nullset, the measure is zero, may be You mean its Hausdorff measure?

Comment: @PeterMelech it's with respect to the circle alone. He's correct. It can be pretty much described as the Lebegue measure of this parametrization. i. e. $m(\{ e^{it} | t\in A\}) = \lambda (A)$, where $A\subset [0, 2\pi]$ and $\lambda $ is the Lebesgue measure on the real line.

Comment: @PeterMelech: Note the difference between **on** the unit circle and **of** the unit circle.

Comment: @Jakobian@PhoemueX I see, I wouldn't call it a Lebesgue measure though, Lebesgue measure of the parametrization makes sense of course

Comment: @PeterMelech it's a popular name for it. In general we talk about the $d-1$ dimensional Lebegue measure on a $d-1$ dimensional sphere

Comment: @Jakobian what is the normalisation of the measure, shouldn't it vary by parametrisation?

Comment: @Jakobian OK, Thanks,didn't hear this before. Then it coincides with the Hausdorff measure, but of course for this You have to  see the circle as embedded in the space $\mathbb{R}^2$